# I want make TimepickerDialog but I found this error

Tags: android

I'm try to use TimepickerDialog but the application is crash
this is screenshot showing the error message in android monitor

Comment: Where is your error?

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/icu/util/Calendar;
                                                                           at com.example.emad.time.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:35)

Comment: show your code as well so we can understand

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the normal [java.util.Calendar](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) instead of the [android.icu.util.Calendar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/util/Calendar.html) which is just introduced in API 24. So if you run your app with Android devices below 7.0 (API < 24) it will crash and produce `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Try to use this import `java.util.Calendar` instead of this import `android.icu.util.Calendar`.